# highstock linked to spreadsheet data doesn't work anymore

Tags: highcharts

Suddenly, all my charts no longer show the data that are taken from Google Spreadsheet. They Were online since 2019.
I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
I have searched the web and all the fiddle examples I have seen give the same error.

here is an example page of the problem: https://lapis.finance/test-graph/

Can anyone tell me what could have happened and what the problem is?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It happened because of the last google update regarding google sheets and unfortunately, it affected the Highcharts too. Currently, we're working on fixing this issue as soon as possible. You can follow the ticket on our GitHub to check the progress: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16210